# Auto login with Azure outside of VPN

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, electron, azure-active-directory

I'm currently working on a SPA with Electron that uses Azure to log the user in. For this, I'm passing the "domain_hint" query string in the authorize request to by-pass the login screen. Indeed, the user is inside a specific domain, so it gets logged in without any prompt.

I tried this connected to a VPN, and it works. However, when I disconnect from the VPN, it does not work anymore. I kind of understand why but then I'm wondering how I could work around this. I'm thinking about application such as Teams or OneDrive that ask you to login once then never ask it again, how is it working? Can I do the same with my Electron app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for teams, it uses modern authentication adal or msal, it's also an electron app. once the user logs in teams will store the access token in a cookie and maybe refresh token? then everytime you start it up, it will just use that. so yes, you can do something similar. you just have to store the relevant token. and grab it from storage to use

Comment: Are you sure ? Because I checked msdn and they say that if I have a refresh token and change my password, the token gets invalidated. However, if I change my password, I don't need to login again on Teams.

Comment: per here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetimes-with-confidential-client-refresh-tokens if it is a confidential client refresh tokens don't get revoked even on voluntary password reset.  per here, teams stores token. https://books.google.ca/books?id=4ppiDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=teams+store+the+refresh+token&source=bl&ots=GKdYcqeFju&sig=ACfU3U2mbBpB8kE0NelSZTZYpH2RGxkCig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4pNqok5PqAhU2FjQIHRuLDiwQ6AEwC3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=teams%20store%20the%20refresh%20token&f=false

Comment: "voluntary password reset" includes password changing then? That's nice. One last question... If I'm not wrong, confidential client uses client secret string. However, Electron apps are considered as public client, so it's discouraged to use client_secret query string with that. Mainly because it is difficult to store this client_secret safely. So how does Teams work around this?

Comment: that's a very good question. I'm not 100% sure to be honest. but I suspect it does something similar to this article: https://medium.com/passportjs/pkce-support-for-oauth-2-0-e3a77013b278  i think it uses pkce to mitigate security issues created.

Comment: Yeah, I get the PKCE but it does not apply to my question though. Indeed, I'm already using PKCE to mitigate that but a) I need to store the client_secret somewhere to get the access_token, b) I need to store the access_token. For b) I guess using keytar would be acceptable but the client_secret must be protected and that, I don't really know how to do :-)

Comment: I decided to store the refresh_token into the key vault using keytar. As the token is obtained dynamically (not hard coded), the security level is acceptable as the user can't get it by decompilig the application. For the client_secret, I took advantage of the fact that I have a public REST API to proxy the call to the authorize/token endpoints. Instead of directly calling Azure, I call my route that proxy the call by adding the client_secret query string (for the token endpoint). Works pretty well :-)

Comment: sounds like a nice solution 2 thumbs up :)